# Importing typescript modules while using namespaces/modules

Tags: typescript

I'm facing some compile problems while using namespaces, different files and imports.

```
   //file1.ts
   namespace Blah {
       export class A { 
            static prop: string;
       }
   }

   //file2.ts
   namespace Blah {
       export class B { 

       }
       A.prop = "a";
   }
```

This compiles without error if I dont use any import statement. 
When I put any import statement at the beggining of one of these, i start to get compile errors: namespace Blah is declared but never used. Cannot find name 'A'

I'm trying to use moment as a global, but the @types/moment is not working, and when I try to import it my code does not compile anymore.

Comment: namespaces and modules (including imports) are incompatible.